# Does Windows Server 2012 support the Beep() winapi function?

Tags: windows, winapi, beep

My office recently transitioned from running Windows 7 to using remote desktop sessions running on Windows Server 2012. Some VBA macros I was using include calls to the "Beep" function in the Windows API, which I used as an audio alert that execution had completed. This is the version of "Beep" that takes in a frequency parameter and a duration parameter, and plays a beep of that frequency in Hz for that duration in ms. On the new system, however, no sound is played, and there is no delay after calls to the function. Did Microsoft remove the Beep function in Server 2012?

EDIT: this is a ***different*** question than the linked discussion about Beep in Windows 7. I was previously using this code on Windows 7 without any problems. I have checked that my computer's speakers are turned on, that they are plugged in, and that the system volume is not muted. The behavior here is that Beep() is being treated as a null; nothing happens when it is executed. If the sound were simply muted, the code would at least delay until the indicated number of milliseconds had elapsed; instead, Beep() is skipped like it's not there at all in my code. Take, for example, the following code:

```
Sub beepTest()
k = Beep(523, 5000)
MsgBox("All Done!")
End Sub
```

On the old Windows 7 system, the computer would play a tone over the plugged in speakers for 5 seconds, then pop up with the message box. When running inside the Server 2012 RDP, however, the call to Beep() is essentially ignored, and the message box appears instantaneously, **without a 5 second delay**. This means that it can **not** be just an unplugged or muted sound device; if it were, there would be no sound audible, but there *would* still be a delay, similar to calling the Sleep() function. I wanted to know whether Microsoft had possibly removed support for this API in Server 2012, which would explain why my code isn't working as intended.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266599/why-dont-i-hear-any-sound-after-calling-the-beep-function-in-windows-7

Comment: These days, the Beep function normally routes to the PC's sound card. Did you configure the remote desktop session to have sounds "Play on this computer" instead of "Play on remote computer"?

Comment: Is the volume settings adjusted appropriately on both the local and remote computer?

Comment: All other sound sources play back at an appropriate volume. The only problem is with the Beep function.

Comment: If it fails, `Beep` will return zero. If so[`GetLastError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms679360.aspx) should provide details as to what went wrong.

Comment: @Simon MᶜKenzie Thank you for the suggestion. The `GetLastError` function returned an error code of "2", which appears to mean "file not found". Could this mean that the kernel32.dll file on my system just doesn't contain the function `Beep`?

Comment: You could check for the presence of `Beep` using [`dumpbin`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177429): `dumpbin c:\windows\system32\kernel32.dll /exports | findstr Beep`...

Comment: I don't have Visual Studio on my computer, so I had to use a 3rd-party workaround to get the export of the DLL. Beep does appear, with ordinal 111 and an RVA of 000131DB. I have no idea what those numbers mean, but I presume they are important.

Comment: I'd think that if it's there, that should be all you'd need, but I'm no expert! One final suggestion, if you're running a 32-bit app on your 64-bit OS, is to do the same check on `c:\windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll`.